# how to create list using text file in python

Tags: python, list

```
file = open('todos.txt', 'r')
todos = file.readline()
file.close()
```

When I then try to use this later in my program, I get the following error:

```
Enter a todo :dance
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\py projects\experiments\2.py", line 12, in <module>
todos.append(todo)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I have to create a list so i needed todos as a list which is not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readlines` to get a list of lines, like so:

```
with open("todos.txt", "r") as f:
    todos = f.readlines()
```

In your solution, the call to `readline` gets one line as a string, which is why you can't append to it.

Answer (score 0):

`file.readline` is of type string and string doesn't have `append` method.
whereas `file.readlines` if of type list and have `append` method.

you need to use `todos = file.readlines()` instead of `todos = file.readline()`